# Ubuntu And Windows Dual Booting Problem

Tags: dual-boot

Today I set up a dual boot on my computer. First I installed Windows 7, then I installed Ubuntu 12.04. The installation completed, I logged in to Ubuntu, after a few minutes, I restarted my computer and tried to login to Windows 7, but Windows Startup is damaged.  I can see the Windows welcome screen after my computer restarts, I'm trying to repair Windows 7, but can't do it.  How do I fix this problem, please help me.

Comment: If you can login from Ubuntu , try this command in Terminal `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: Please indicate your [Boot-Info URL](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info).

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem with Ubuntu not booting up, a friend of mine gave me a ubuntu boot disk repair.

Here is the web address https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair
Other google ubuntu boot disk repair.

Read on if you want more details, otherwise look at the web address above.

My friend googled it "ubuntu boot disk repair" it's a cd that auto runs and it loads it own GUI with it's own browser(if needed) and the boot repair program.
You can repair the grub or the MBR, the grub repaired the linux side for me and the MBR got windows loading up.

I had a few issues when I updated Ubuntu 12.04 a few times and ran the cd a further few times, on the 3rd time needing to use the boot disk I played around with some settings and now it says something about missing kernal headers, to solve this I went back to previous versions in the GRUB.

Answer (score 0):

You have to repair Windows 7 first as repairing Ubuntu booting does not help in any way in this case.

If you have Windows 7 installation/repair DVD/USB just boot it und

1) Run 3 consecutive times "StartUp Repair" with rebooting after each run.

Now you should be able to boot Windows 7.

2) Repair Ubuntu booting -
Reinstall GRUB to MBR (will pick up Win 7 for dual boot).

---

Alternatively see [here](http://www.boyans.net/DualBootWindows7andLinuxOrUnix.html) how you can boot Linux/Unix from Windows 7.